# XMonad cycle through all windows on visible workspaces

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm using XMonad on a dual screen set up, and would like to be able to cycle focus through every window visible on either screen (say, with alt+tab). The behavior would be similar to XMonad.Actions.WindowNavigation, except it wouldn't be bound to a direction, and just cycle through them in some order that makes sense (left to right, top to bottom for instance).

I've found some code [here](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/xmonad/2009-October/008995.html) that claims to manipulate the StackSet to solve this problem, and I got it to compile but it wouldn't do what I wanted. Unfortunately my understanding of Haskell is pretty limited, so I've been unable to either write my own or fix whatever is wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `CycleWS` module in [xmonad-contrib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib)

It has bindings that you can use to cycle through non-empty workspaces:

```
import XMonad.Actions.CycleWS

myKeys homeDir conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
    [ -- (your own bindings here)
    -- Cycle non-empty workspaces with mod+tab or mod+shift+tab
    , ((modm              , xK_Tab   ), moveTo Next NonEmptyWS)
    , ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Tab   ), moveTo Prev NonEmptyWS)
    ]
```

My full config is [here](https://github.com/alexj136/dotfiles/blob/c2bbd1dd9e1c2a151e0f796f30c38af74865e41c/xmonad/xmonad.hs) if you want a complete example.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think that CycleWS lets me cycle through workspaces, but what I actually want to do is be able to move focus across windows, without actually cycling workspaces. So if I had two screens, with workspace 1 and 2 visible and I'm currently focused on a window in workspace 1, I would like to be able to bind alt-tab to move focus across all windows open in workspace 1 and 2. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has since been added to xmonad-contrib by this [pull request](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad-contrib/issues/293).

Example usage:

```
import XMonad.Actions.GroupNavigation
```

within the keys section

```
-- use Alt+Tab and Alt+Shift+Tab to change focus to different windows across workspaces
((alt,           xK_Tab   ), nextMatch Forward isOnAnyVisibleWS),
((alt .|. shift, xK_Tab   ), nextMatch Backward isOnAnyVisibleWS),
```